# Twig: comments in {% javascripts %}

Tags: javascript, symfony, twig

I have a situation like this in my twig file:

```
{% javascripts
    'js/functions.js'
    'js/plugins.js'
    'js/editor.js'
    'js/calendar.js'
%} [...]
```

And I would love to comment some scripts out using

```
{% javascripts
    {# 'js/functions.js' #}
    'js/plugins.js'
    'js/editor.js'
    'js/calendar.js'
%} [...]
```

But this isnt allowed, I get an `Unexpected character "#"` error.

Is there a common practice how to handle this?

Comment: I believe you'll have to remove `js/functions.js` line. You can move it to separate comment, just to remember that it was there.

Comment: @Crozin, okay. This is the way I'm doing it now, but it's not very handy.

Comment: this is what version control was built for, you shouldn't have to leave commented code in your files long term

Comment: @Jaitsu yes and no. Since the order of the script matters, I need to have it somewhere. But generally you're correct of course, dead code is ugly as hell. Best variant for my problem is probably to leave a complete block commented out on purpose somewhere in a template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is unsupported twig syntax, obviously. So it's up to you how to hide it. I would do something like this:

```
{#    'js/functions.js'#}
{% javascripts
    'js/plugins.js'
    'js/editor.js'
    'js/calendar.js'
%} [...]
```